# Google chrome slows down while opening a new webpage?

Tags: google-chrome, performance

Whenever I hit CTRL + T new tab same when i hit Home tab and write any url for first 10-15 seconds it just doesn't show anything, hangs for any webpage including the fastest www.google.co.in?

Can anyone tell me why this is happening?

Even when I open chrome://settings anything it takes time?

Add-ons I've installed google docs, ad block plus, google url short.

Comment: It might be your DNS. If the DNS is slow to respond then the IP address of the machine your trying to contact will not be available until the DNS has responded. However if this is the case then you should see lagging problems elsewhere to, not just when your enter an url in google.

Comment: If the problem is with DNS, then how come chrome://settings page also taking time to open? and If i check with Internet explorer it's working fine.